# what do i call the font?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I went to bulletproof @font-face and tried to use that as a template to embed a font into my website and it is not working. I want to use  **perspective-sans black regular**. I uploaded four files to my server: the css style sheet that came with the kit, and this font's eot, ttf, and woff files. I am wondering what is wrong? The font that is there now a default font.

http://swarthmorebahais.org/

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'persanbk'; src:
            url('persanbk-webfont.eot') format('eot'), 
            url('persanbk-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
            url('persanbk-webfont.ttf') format('truetype')
}

#h2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left:-351px;
    width:702px;
    height:60px;
    font:50px persanbk, sans serif;
    color:#cc0257;
}

 <div id='h2'>
            The earth is but one country,
        </div>
```

Comment: That is not true. Using the @fontface declaration is a acceptable way of doing it and is fully supported in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like to me that you have 404 error's for the font files, I would check that they are in the correct place, your code says that they should be at the root fo your site, for example: "http://swarthmorebahais.org/persanbk-webfont.eot" is one of the 404ing fonts expected locations.

Comment: extremely helpful. solved my problem right away. Many many thank, DrCord.